# Attempting to draw a grid in Android using drawRect getting strange output

Tags: java, android

I'm attempting to draw a grid of rectangle objects for a Game of Life application. At this stage im just trying to get the base grid to work. Eventually it will evaluate a boolean array for live and dead cells and change the paint style accordingly. I've simplified the code as much as I can for testing purposes. Im attempting to draw a 9x6 grid of 100x100 rectangles with no padding.

Here is my code:

```
    paintGrid.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);    //sets paint style for grid squares 
    int gm = 100; //gridMultiplier determines rectangle size in this case 100x100

    for(int r = 0; r < 9; r++) //paints grid with 9 rows
    {
        for(int c = 0; c < grid[0].length; c++) //6 columns 
        {
            top = r*gm; //sets LEFT side
            bottom = top+gm; //sets RIGHT side
            left = c*gm;
            right = left+gm; 
            Log.v(LOGTAG, "left: " + left + " right: "+ right+ " top: " + top +
                  " bottom: " + bottom); //testing
            canvas.drawRect(left, top, bottom, right, paintGrid); //paints dead Cell
        }
    }
```

I would expect this to draw a grid by first drawing the top row left to right, then the second row, and continue until complete. 
[Instead I get this for an output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNfQP.png)

The logcat output im using for testing seem to indicate the loop is working properly. I get: 
Left: 0 right 100 top 0 bottom 100
Left: 100 right 200 top 0 bottom 100
Left: 200 right 300 top 0 bottom 100 
Left: 300 right 400 top 0 bottom 100 
Left: 400 right 500 top 0 bottom 100

Left 0 right 100 top 100 bottom 200 
left 100 right 200 top 100 bottom 200 
left 200 right 300 top 100 bottom 200 
... etc

Im at my wits ends here! I was under the impression that 2D arrays are row major so ive been trying to keep that setup. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have switched the right and bottom arguments. The right order is left, top, right, bottom. The result you is produced since android needs right > left and bottom > top or it wont draw the rectangle at all. So your code only draws the ones in the diagonal where it isn't relevant due to bottom = right.